# Form Post data not being sent after setting htacces rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the PHP-login.net framework for a login and I am hosting the folder in a subfolder of another website and using htaccess to redirect it to the main domain I created for that subfolder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?decathlon.ga$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/decathlon/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /decathlon/$1 [L]
```

It worked fine when I had it just as saint57records.com/decathlon but when I added the redirect the POST data is not being sent from this form. However, all links are redirecting as they should.

```
<form action="http://decathlon.ga/login/login" method="post">
<label>Username (or email)</label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" required />
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="user_password" required />
<input type="checkbox" name="user_rememberme" class="remember-me-checkbox" />
<label class="remember-me-label">Keep me logged in (for 2 weeks)</label>
<input type="submit" class="login-submit-button" />
</form>
```

On the page it goes to it performs this check and gives me the error that the POST is empty.

`http://decathlon.ga/login/login` portion below

```
if (!isset($_POST['user_name']) OR empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
    $_SESSION["feedback_negative"][] = FEEDBACK_USERNAME_FIELD_EMPTY;
    return false;
}
```

So everything is redirecting to the right place but does someone understand what might be going on with the POST data because of the redirect?

Comment: You're not posting to the page that you're redirecting to.

Comment: So how do I post to the right page, because the form is going to the correct page, is the POST data going somewhere else?

Comment: Side note; You might want to use `||` instead of `OR`

Comment: The POST data is going to the first stop, then you redirect and the POST data is left behind.

Comment: is there a way to carry it with the redirect?

Comment: @Core `OR` is perfectly acceptable but `||` has a [greater precedence.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: You could carry the data using `$_SESSION` and destroy the variables when you no longer need them.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh, I thought that `OR` was deprecated. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shown rule is **not doing any external redirect**, it is just an internal rewriting. Hence POST data will be **preserved** during this routing to `/decathlon` directory. I would suggest you to check presence of other rules doing this redirect. External redirect can also be caused by other module like `mod_dir` if `login/login` is a real directory.

As an alternative you can even avoid this rewrite by directly using `/decathlon/` in the form's action path:

```
<form action="http://decathlon.ga/decathlon/login/login"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to do, but you are redirecting everything not matching `^/decathlon/.*$` to `/decathlon/$1`. That means that `http://decathlon.ga/login/login` redirects to `http://decathlon.ga/decathlon/login/login`, which seems wrong.

You need to rewrite your second `RewriteCond` and your `RewriteRule`, but it's impossible to guess what they should be without more information.

Comment: this is hosted under http://saint57records.com/decathlon, so when I have a link come in from decathlon.ga I want it to use that subdirectory

Comment: Well, the rules you have aren't really going to work. You are probably better off using relative URLs. Also, some more clarity in your question about exactly what you need to do would help.

Comment: But the rewrite rule works exactly how I want it, all URLs are going exactly where they are supposed to. My problem is that the POST data is not being kept

Comment: Something is missing here. Do you have any JavaScript or additional PHP that does anything with the form data? Try adding `echo __FILE__ . "<br/>";` at the top of your PHP script and see what output you get. It sounds like you might be calling a different script than you expect.